# cannnot focus element in dropdown test

Tags: angularjs, protractor, gulp-protractor

This is my dropdown in angular

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Select Entity:</label>
<select class="form-control" id="sel1">
<option value="Select">Select</option>
<option value="Test">Test</option>
</select>
</div>
```

protractor test case is this:

```
var entity = element(by.id('sel1')).click();
var option =    element(by.tagName('option[value="Test"]')).click();
```

i am getting error in protractor :

> Failed: unknown error: cannot focus element

Comment: Your tag name locator value is incorrect. This inspired me to plan to warn above this kind of violations statically: https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor/issues/59.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var entity = element(by.id('sel1')).click();
var option = element(by.cssContainingText('option', 'Test')).click();
```

Comment: You missed the `quotes` inside `element(by.cssContainingText('option', 'Test'))`

Comment: fixed bro... Thanks